# What formula does SPSS apply to the data in an ANCOVA?

Tags: statistics, formula, spss, ancova

The procedure for an ANOVA is really straightforward; you compute the between group variance and the within group variance, divide your results to get an F statistic, and compare it to your critical value.

But what about ANCOVA? I can't find an exact procedure anywhere. Can someone show me a piece of code to find the F statistic in an ANCOVA? And not just using pre-built ANCOVA modules, because what I am interested in is how the resulting F statistic is obtained.

I tried researching the ANCOVA formula, but to no avail. I am expecting the formula.

Comment: This question feels better suited for Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com). It seems like you're more interested in information about a statistical procedure than solving a particular coding problem.

Comment: @GregorThomas I do want to know how to code an ANCOVA without any external modules, like how we can do it for ANOVA.

Comment: Well, let me suggest you ask a question at stats.stackexchange to learn the equation you want to code up, and then if you have trouble implementing it, that would be a good question here.